# What's going on here with my freshly compiled perl?

Tags: perl

I compiled perl with a relocatable @INC as follows:

```
$ sh Configure -des -D prefix=~/perl -Duserelocatableinc
```

After I set up my path etc I get the following:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; print "ok"'
Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ../lib/site_perl/5.12.4/darwin-2level ../lib/site_perl/5.12.4 ../lib/5.12.4/darwin-2level ../lib/5.12.4 .) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

If I do this though, everything it's all OK?

```
$ `which perl` -e 'use strict; print "ok"'
```

Have I done something wrong?  This is on OS X.

Here's the output for perl -V:

```
$ perl -V
Can't locate Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains:     ../lib/site_perl/5.12.4/darwin-2level ../lib/site_perl/5.12.4     ../lib/5.12.4/darwin-2level ../lib/5.12.4 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

$ `which perl` -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 12 subversion 4) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=darwin, osvers=10.8.0, archname=darwin-2level
    uname='darwin fenchurch-2.local 10.8.0 darwin kernel version 10.8.0: tue     jun 7 16:33:36 pdt 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1release_i386 i386 '
    config_args='-des -D prefix=/Users/kd/perl -Duserelocatableinc'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=undef, usemultiplicity=undef
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -no-cpp-precomp     -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include     -I/opt/local/include',
    optimize='-O3',
    cppflags='-no-cpp-precomp -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -no-cpp-precomp     -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include     -I/opt/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)',     gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t',     lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3 cc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector     -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /opt/local/lib /usr/lib
    libs=-lgdbm -ldbm -ldl -lm -lutil -lc
    perllibs=-ldl -lm -lutil -lc
    libc=/usr/lib/libc.dylib, so=dylib, useshrplib=false, libperl=libperl.a
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=bundle, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags=' -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup     -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV PERL_MALLOC_WRAP USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO
                        USE_PERL_ATOF
  Built under darwin
  Compiled at Jul 16 2011 15:44:19
  %ENV:
    PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT="1"
  @INC:
    /Users/kd/perl/lib/site_perl/5.12.4/darwin-2level
    /Users/kd/perl/lib/site_perl/5.12.4
    /Users/kd/perl/lib/5.12.4/darwin-2level
    /Users/kd/perl/lib/5.12.4
    .
```

Comment: What did you install perl with?

Comment: Is there any chance you have an alias for perl?

Comment: no aliases for perl.  I installed perl with the configure command above, then make && make test && make install

Comment: well I can fix it by putting an alias in my ~/.bashrc.  But that seems silly.

Comment: Try printing `@INC` with both "which perl" and "perl". After reading the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.10.1/INSTALL#Relocatable_@INC), I have a feeling you have some weird synergy going between the `-Dprefix` and `-Duserelocatableinc`. The "../" in @INC should be replaced with the path of the executable, but it is not.

Comment: Can you include the @INC part of the output of `perl -V` (at the very bottom)?

Comment: running the output of `which perl` runs a different perl than running `perl`? Something smells.

Comment: looks like a bug.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found a bug report:

http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2011/03/msg169818.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you get anything for `perl -V`? Using the capital V shows the version and the compilation options, including the `@INC` directories. Ensure those directories are where the modules are.

Also note that in `prefix`, you're nominating the directory for installation, so `perl` should be in *~/perl/bin/perl*. Is that the `perl` you are running? I wouldn't expect `which` to find that unless you have already adjusted your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine a scenario where you would rather precompile the Perl interpreter with a new @INC path rather than just setting it into the environment or establishing it in the Perl script itself.

Compiling a new lib path into Perl seems excessive and fragile.

I think you're much better off passing it as an argument:

```
PERL5LIB="/my/new/path":$PERL5LIB /path/to/my/script.pl
```

or inside the script itself, since you already know the path required:

```
push(@INC, "/my/new/path");
```

Comment: "I can't imagine a scenario where you would rather precompile the Perl interpreter with a new @INC path rather than just setting it into the environment or establishing it in the Perl script itself. " If you're using perl for applications development, don't use the system perl, use your own.  The system perl is for the system, and it's quite common for vendors to ship with either a broken perl or to pull the rug from under you.